# onAreaTouched is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine in Android but it is not working correctly. I am designing backgammon board and stones with animated sprites. When the scene is touched with `stones(isActionDown)`, the stone is dragged to move up or down.

The code of animated sprite is:

```
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX,
            float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            float tx = 0,ty=0;
            float px=0,py=0;

            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
            {
                tx=pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                ty=pSceneTouchEvent.getY();

                //System.out.println("initial-->\n"+"Gray1.getX(): "+Gray1.getX()+"Gray1.getY(): "+Gray1.getY());
            }
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove())
            {

                Gray1.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - mGrayStoneTexture1.getWidth()/2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - mGrayStoneTextureRegion1.getHeight()/2);
                px=pSceneTouchEvent.getX();
                py=pSceneTouchEvent.getY();
                //System.out.println("move-->\n"+"Gray1.getX(): "+Gray1.getX()+"Gray1.getY(): "+Gray1.getY());
            }
            //System.out.println("tx: "+ tx + "ty: " + ty + "px: "+ px + "py: " + py);
            return false;
        }
    };
```

How to fix the code to work correctly?

Comment: What is not working? What happens currently? What is the expected result?

Comment: When I touched scene and drag other coordinates,stone is constantly going up and when going down to drag it cannot change its direction and going up constantly.I expect when touch scene get x and y coordinates and when I flipped the mouse on the scene move on flipping coordinates.sorry my english is not good.

Comment: hi, I tried to make backgammon game on android, but I have not decided what I will use the library. So do I need to take advantage of the libraries for backgammon game? I did some andengine library onto the interface, but not quite, because the drag portion of backgammon while dragging the mouse move, click, and always moving upwards. How do I solve the problem. Waiting for your help. thanks (sorry  for my english)

Comment: Take a look at this thread: [AndEngine - scroll sprites up and down][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21798528/andengine-scroll-sprites-up-and-down/21842037#21842037

Comment: change your return type to true for onAreaTouch() method.Also make scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);.It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `return true;` in the end of

```
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
```

and

```
if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove())
```

Example:

```
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown())
            {
                ...
                return true;
            }
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove())
            {
                ...
                return true;
            }
```